# How do I import an Android library and use it in both production code and tests?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-library

I've extracted a bunch of functionality from my app into a library. The problem is I'd like to make use of the library classes in both production code and tests. The issue is that my app, my library, and the test code are separate modules, so both the app code and the test code need to depend on the library. When I try to compile the test module, I get the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: (some class)
```

It's cryptic, but it's trying to say that I've tried to add the same class to the `.dex` file more than once. It's not too surprising since the test code depends on the library code and on the app at compile time, which also depends on the library at compile time. How do I set up my dependencies (or change my code) to avoid this?

*NOTE:* I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 CE, so I use their terminology, but I think the problem is at least conceptually IDE-agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in IDEA, we've submitted an issue for it, [please watch/vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-70343).

Comment: Thank you very much. When it's fixed I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I feel the same jar is added multiple times using different ways.

There is two ways of putting jar in your project

```
Right on Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add Jars->
Right on Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add External jars->
```

first remove all jars. inside your application folder create a folder there put all the required jars.

```
Right on Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Add Jars-> select your project folder and select the jar file
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Deepak. My problem is slightly different, because my library isn't a simple .jar. It's an Android library project, so I've imported it as a separate module and added a module dependency to it.